# How to fetch a project from launchpad

Tags: development

I would like to play a little bit with elementary programs. Could someone provide me a guide how to fetch a trunk from launchpad and run that trunk on my pc?

I'm really a rookie in things like git.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

elementary OS doesn't use Git. It uses Bazaar, which is an alternative to Git.

To fetch some part of elementary OS from Launchpad:

1. Go here: https://launchpad.net/elementary
2. In your browser, select a project on the right side that you want to fetch (I'm going to use Scratch as an example) and then click on the `Code` on the top.
3. You'll see the Bazaar command that you'll need to enter in Terminal to fetch the code. Here's an example:

   `bzr branch lp:scratch`
4. This command is going to create a subfolder in the current working directory and name it `scratch`. Once the command is executed, `cd` into that subfolder and then try to build the code by referring to the file called `INSTALL` or `HACKING` that will guide you through the process.